# How to access a dictionary within a class?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, python-import

I'm accessing a class from another Python file by importing it at the top of the file.  The class looks something like this:

```
class Something(object):
    a_dictionary = {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}

    def __init__(self):
        stuff....
```

My question is how would I be able to access `a_dictionary` from the other file.  I can't seem to find how to access a dictionary not within a function in another file.

I'm a beginner in Python and I have looked everywhere to find this answer and I can't.  I essentially need to be able to iterate through the above dictionary from the other file.

Comment: `Something.a_dictionary` ?

Comment: for more insight into the topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
from your_module import Something
print (Something.a_dictionary) # prints {1: 2, ...}
```

Answer (score 1):

in this case, `a_dictionary` is a class variable, and therefore part of the object's `__dict__`. You would access this dictionary in another file like this:

```
from your_file import Something

new_object = Something()
print(new_object.a_dictionary)
```

Accessing a class variable is done the same way as accessing an instance variable. The only difference between a class variable and instance variable is that class variables are the same value across **all** instances of an object, whereas an instance variable is specific to a single instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
import otherfile

print(otherfile.Something.a_dictionary[1])
```

> Output

```
2
```

Comment: @MarcusLind I reverted your edit, because it changed the code in this answer significantly.  If you want to do things in a different fashion, post an answer of your own.

Comment: I thought he wanted to access to a dictionary in a class of another file... so I imported the file and printed the dictionary... wasn't that the goal of the questions?

Comment: I guess the upvotes were awarded at a time when this answer contained incorrect code.